# Android getStringArray returns only lower case

Tags: android, xml, resources, lowercase

I'm quite new at this and would really appreciate any help on this.

I'm using `getStringArray()` to retrieve an array with strings. Each string has the first letter upper case. But when the array is loaded into the java array, all letters are lower case.

The array from arrays.xml:

```
    <string-array name="playerformatnames">
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Orange</item>
        <item>Yellow</item>        
        <item>Green</item>
        <item>Blue</item>
        <item>Violet</item>
    </string-array>
```

The code to load the array:

```
    String[] playerFormatNames = 
        context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.playerformatnames);
```

This will result in array contents: "red", "orange", yellow", ...
The upper case characters are gone.

So my questions are:

- Is this normal behaviour?
- Am I doing it wrong if i want to keep the upper case letters?
- Is it a bug / misconfiguration of Eclipse?

Thank you!

Comment: how are you displaying the array contents?

Comment: In several ways:
- In textviews
- In HashMap to find an integer value
But I actually run the app in Debug mode and displayed the array contents just after the java line shown above and ecplise displays all strings in lower case...

Comment: @Koniak  could you give an example of how you're displaying them?

Comment: ( I first discovered the problem when I couldn't get a match in the HashMap using "Red". I then used Debug mode to look at the string directly after getStringArray and noticed they where all lower case)

Comment: TextView tvHeading = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvplayinggamelheading);
        tvHeading.setText(currentPlayerUI.getPlayerFormat().getName());

Comment: But as I said, the eclipse debuger shows the value of array "playerFormatNames" as ALL lowercase directly after:

        String[] playerFormatNames =
        context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.playerformatnames);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't noticed this issue before but it certainly seems like a concern, as nasty as what I am about to suggest sounds it may be necessary. You might want to try something like this to preserve all formatting.

```
<string-array name="playerformatnames">
  <item><![CDATA[Red]]></item>
  ...
</string-array>
```

Which is to say, wrap the content of each element in `CDATA`.

Comment: Thank you Quintin.

Scary.... I did this to test:
    <string-array name="playerformatnames">
     <item><![CDATA[Red]]></item>
        <item>Orange</item>
        <item>Yellow</item>        
        <item>Green</item>
        <item>Blue</item>
        <item>Violet</item>
 </string-array>

Now all entries show up with first character upper case!

What does CDATA do?

Comment: @Koniak Well CDATA (being character data) basically denotes a portion of the content that *should not* be parsed by the xml interpreter, so generally is for use of embedding illegal content into an xml document but in this case just preservation of case or formatting.

Comment: @Koniak also I noticed you seem to be new here, when an answer has solved your question you should mark it as accepted, this is helpful for the community as other people will have the same issue and can easily see the solution. You can review the FAQ on how to accomplish this here (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) as well as for further etiquette, glad you got your problem solved!

Comment: Now I changed it back by removing CDATA again and it still works fine... Seems like Eclipse had cached some old version of the arrays.xml and when I changed it with CDATA it was recompiled. Some ADK bug? Well everything works fine now!
Thank you for your time and help!